# Is there a way to upload an app bundle or apk to Google Play WITHOUT using Google Play Signing?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-app-bundle, android-signing

I want to upload my app to the Google Play Store, but I may also distribute it on other platforms. The distributed APKs must be signed by the same key if I want the users to be able to update the app from other sources.

In 2024 is it even possible to use my own key to sign the distributed apk in the Google Play Store?

Here is where I started:

[image: Create production release screen]

Back in the day, if you wanted to use your own key, you just had to drop in the APK/AAB, and the key that you used for signing the file became 'finalized' as your signing key for distribution.

Now I can't even upload a file without choosing a signing key.

If I click on "Choose signing key" I do get the option of adding my own key, but as far as I'm aware it seems to just be an 'upload key', used to make sure that an authorized party uploaded the apk to the Play Console, but Google will be the one to actually sign the distributed apk that gets to the end user.

[image]

I clicked on "Use a different key" and I went through the steps of adding my own signing key

[image]

Once I'm done uploading my signing key, it says "Releases signed by Google Play".

[image]

Is there a way to avoid Google Play Signing?

Note: I know that once Google Play Signing is enabled it is permanently enabled **for the app**, thankfully I'm in a position where I have yet to release my application, so I am able to delete and recreate the app as many times as needed.

Comment: "Is there a way to avoid Google Play Signing?" -- acquire an existing app on the Play Store and its signing key. Otherwise, I do not know of any way to avoid Play App Signing, as it has been required for a few years, despite [its issues](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/09/23/uncomfortable-questions-app-signing.html).

Comment: go to AppIntigrity Tab in play console and check that if there is also "Signing by Google Play
" written in front of app signing